# How to connect to database in class construct function?

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

## Code

**connect.php**

```
$username   = "USERNAME";
$password   = "PASSWORD";
$hostname   = "HOSTNAME";
$dbname     = 'DATABASE';

try { $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); }

catch(PDOException $e){ echo($e->getMessage()); }
```

**users.php**

```
include "/connect.php";

class User
{   
    private $id, $name1, $name2, $email, $pic, $league_id;

    //Constructor
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($id));
        if($stmt->rowCount()<1) exit("Could not find user");
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $this->id = $row["id"];
        $this->name1 = $row["name1"];
        $this->name2 = $row["name2"];
        $this->pic = $row["pic"];
        $this->league_id = $row["league_id"];
    }

    //functions - Get
    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function getName1(){ return $this->name1; }
    public function getName2(){ return $this->name2; }
    public function getFullName() { return $this->name1 . " " . $this->name2; }
    public function getPic(){ return $this->pic; }
    public function getLeagueId(){ return $this->league_id; }
}
```

**index.php**

```
if(isLoggedIn()) {
    $user = new User($_SESSION["userid"]);
    echo "Welcome back, ".$user->getFullName()."!";
}
```

## Issue

I'm new to classes and OOP in PHP so apologies for the code.

I connect to the database in `connect.php`, however I'm having difficulty processing queries in the `__constructor` function.

I understand that I cannot `include` the connection in the constructor. I also see that the code works if I directly insert the code from `connect.php` into the function.

However, I don't want to have to connect to the database each time I want to make a query; is there a method for me to connect *outside* of the `__construct` function?

**As far as being a duplicate, the linked question *does not* answer this one. My question is: "How can I access the object in `/connect.php` in the `__construct` function of my object?"**

Comment: The duplicate gives pretty clear options: `global` (no no!), or passing it as a parameter. Or `include` the file inside your constructor; I have no idea why you think that's not possible.

Comment: Pass object variable to class scope or use global

Comment: Re now-deleted-comment: Exactly. You may want to read [this](http://kunststube.net/static), which illuminates a bit why. Since this can arguably get tedious, your class structure can be improved a lot. You'd generally want one "repository" class which you instantiate once and which gets a database connection once, and this repository can then instantiate and return User objects to you.

Comment: @deceze It doesn't work when I `include` the file, that's why I think it's not possible...

Comment: You can put `global $dbh;` at the top of `__construct`. But I would suggest wrapping the `$dbh` var in a static class. Ex connect.php: `class Connect {  static public $dbh; } Connect::$dbh = new PDO(.....);` Then to use it, `Connect::$dbh->prepare(...);`. Using global variables is an astoundingly bad idea. I did it for a long time and it just made my code terrible. Wrapping it in a class makes it easily accessible anywhere and keeps it neat and organized.

Comment: @Jakar FYI: `static public` variables are essentially the same as global variables! Read [this](http://kunststube.net/static).

Comment: @Ben It's perfectly possible to `include` files within functions, including object constructors.

Comment: @deceze, good read. It is essentially a global variable, but `ClassName::$var` provides a lot more opportunity, usability, and readability than `global $var`. Plus, I'm suggesting that the initialization of the static property be immediately after the class definition (in the same file), and any error handling (of the connection) would be immediately after that. Thus, if `Connect` is available, then it is guaranteed that `Connect::$dbh` is available, and changing the database type only requires changing the database initialization, which is in `connect.php`.

Comment: Though, i realize my suggestion is imperfect and definitely not the most proper OOP. It's simple though and far better than `global $var`. But yeah. static public variables definitely can cause ridiculous pains sometimes, if not planned for appropriately.

Comment: @Jakar Really, everything you just said about static class variables can equally be done with global variables. "If `global $foo` is available, it's guaranteed to be initialized." Just the syntax is different.